# Concurrent nested requests in a microservices environment built with Django

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm developing a microservices architecture with Django in which services communicate each other through RESTful APIs.

A request coming from a client is served by a service, which then requires to make a new (nested) HTTP request to another service as it is shown in the picture below, in order to mantain decoupling between services.

[image]

In this scenario, it may happen that two different requests are fired by the client and served simultaneously by the first service. Then, one of the two nested requests to the second service remains unserved until a 503 error (Service Unavailable) occurs.
It seems that concurrency between nested requests is bad handled by the server.

RESTful APIs are implemented with Django REST framework and nested requests are made with the Python requests library. Here is an example:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
import requests

class FirstServiceView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):

        # Code...

        # The nested requests to the second service
        response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/second_service/")

        # Other code...
```

It's worth noting that this behaviour happens with both the development server of Django and Apache. Furthermore, no concurrency on the database is involved in this case.

Comment: Apparently the second service is set up so that it can only handle one request at a time. How do you run it, behind Apache or so?

Comment: Both services are applications in the same Django project. Thus, requests to both services are served by the same server.

Comment: That's not two different services then, that's just one service with several URLs. It makes no sense to call functionality over HTTP, just call the function in Python and do without all the overhead of going through the outside world.

Comment: But anyway, if this is with the development server, it can only serve 1 request at a time. So if that calls itself while handling a request, it has to wait for itself to finish, it can't work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I thought about this solution as an alternative to the current one. HTTP requests between microservices may be used when such services are running on different servers. But for now, this is not the case.